# Generalizing Oksana's trilogarithm relation to $\text{Li}_3(\frac{n}8)$?

Tags: logarithms, special-functions, closed-form, polylogarithm

This was inspired by [Oksana's post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/935366/simplification-of-an-expression-containing-operatornameli-3x-terms). Let, $$a = \ln 2 \quad\quad\\ b = \ln 3\quad\quad\\ c = \ln 5\quad\quad$$

then the following,

\begin{align}
A &= \text{Li}_3\left(\frac12\right)\\ 
B &= \text{Li}_3\left(\frac13\right)+\text{Li}_3\left(\frac23\right)\\ 
C &= \text{Li}_3\left(\frac14\right)+\text{Li}_3\left(\frac34\right)\\ 
D &= \text{Li}_3\left(\frac15\right)+\text{Li}_3\left(\frac25\right)+\text{Li}_3\left(\frac35\right)+\text{Li}_3\left(\frac45\right)\\ 
E &= \text{Li}_3\left(\frac16\right)+\text{Li}_3\left(\frac56\right)\\
\end{align}

have known expression in terms of $a,b,c,$ ***plus*** other polylogs. Namely,

\begin{align}
12A &= 2a^3-6a\zeta(2)+\tfrac{21}2\zeta(3)\\
12B &=-3\,\text{Li}_3\left(\tfrac14\right)+4a^3+4b^3-6ab^2+6(a-2b)\zeta(2)+\tfrac{45}2\zeta(3)\\
6C &= -12\,\text{Li}_3\left(\tfrac13\right)+16a^3+2b^3-12a^2b-12a\zeta(2)+19\zeta(3)\\
6D &=\, D_1+D_2- 6 (a - 4 b + 2 c)\zeta(2)-\tfrac{19}2\zeta(3)\\
12E &=\, E_1+E_2- 3 (a - 8 b + 4 c) \zeta(2)-\tfrac{63}4\zeta(3)\\
\end{align}

where,

\begin{align}
D_1&=18\,\text{Li}_3\left(\tfrac13\right)+21\,\text{Li}_3\left(\tfrac23\right)-3\,\text{Li}_3\left(\tfrac16\right)-3\,\text{Li}_3\left(\color{blue}{\tfrac38}\right)\\
D_2&=14 a^3 - 6 b^3 + 4 c^3 - 12 a^2 b + 12 a b^2 - 9 a c^2 - 3 b c^2 + 6 a b c\\
\end{align}

and,

\begin{align}
E_1&= 36\,\text{Li}_3\left(\tfrac13\right)+36\,\text{Li}_3\left(\tfrac23\right)-15\,\text{Li}_3\left(\tfrac15\right)-18\,\text{Li}_3\left(\tfrac25\right)-9\,\text{Li}_3\left(\tfrac45\right)+6\,\text{Li}_3\left(\color{blue}{\tfrac58}\right)\\
E_2&=-23 a^3 - 8 b^3 + 7 c^3 + 12 a^2 b + 21 a^2c + 30 a b^2 - 6 b^2 c - 18 a c^2 - 12 a b c \\
\end{align}

Eliminating $\zeta(3)$ between $D$ and $E$, then moving all the polylogs to the LHS and the logarithms to the RHS gives the simplification sought by Oksana in her post.

Note: The relation for $D$ and $E$ were [found by Kirill](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/941061/4781) (though I had to fix some of the typos).

---

**Question:** Can we find a closed-form for, $$F = \text{Li}_3\left(\frac18\right)+\text{Li}_3\left(\frac38\right)+\text{Li}_3\left(\frac58\right)+\text{Li}_3\left(\frac78\right)$$
similar to the others?

Comment: If you arrange these in a matrix you get
$$
\begin{matrix}
A \\ B \\ C \\ D \\ E
\end{matrix}
\sim
\begin{matrix}
1 \\
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}
$$
Searching "1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1" in the OEIS gives A047999 Sierpiński's [Sierpinski's] triangle (or gasket):
Therefore you might also want to investigate 
$$
F = \text{Li}_3\left(\frac17\right)+\text{Li}_3\left(\frac27\right)+\text{Li}_3\left(\frac57\right)+\text{Li}_3\left(\frac67\right)
$$

Comment: @BenedictW.J.Irwin: I'm afraid it may not be the case. Technically, all the entries should be $1$, but since $\text{Li}_3(\frac24)$, $\text{Li}_3(\frac26)+\text{Li}_3(\frac46)$, etc have closed-forms, they are redundant. But I was thinking of including them earlier.